# How to reduce the white space around a scatter plot (using R and ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my scatterplot, there is some empty space left and I haven't managed to reduce it manually or with the `xlim()` command nor with `scale_x_discrete(limits=())`. My code:

```
ggplot(data = doppelratings2_mit_ID, 
aes(x = R1, y = R3)) +
geom_jitter(shape = 1, width = 0.1, height = 0.1) + 
geom_smooth()+
xlab("Rater 1") +
ylab("Rater 3") +
ggtitle("Korrelation zwischen Rater 1 und 3", paste("n = 17 Texte ")) +
theme_bw(12)+
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)+
scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:5, labels = tick_names_5, limits = c(1:5))+
scale_y_discrete(breaks = 1:6, labels = tick_names_6, limits = c(1:6))
```

And the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzo2kswd1wqjsfl/Auswertung_Interrater-Reliabilit%C3%A4t_Vergleich%20R1%20R3%20mit%20ID_f%C3%BCr%20Stackoverflow.xlsx?dl=0):

```
> dput(doppelratings2_mit_ID_für_Stackoverflow)
structure(list(ID = c(6584209, 6598108, 6584103, 6552101, 6608303, 
6656213, 9734115, 9554201, 9554108, 9604202, 6660108, 6520103, 
6726215, 6574106, 9762121, 9688202, 9576108), R1 = c(2, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4), R3 = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -17L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the data used to make the plot so that your example is reproducible?

Comment: Of course, I added it into the question directly and with a link. I hope it works.

Comment: `R1` as well as `R3` are integers. Thus, try to use `scale_x_continuous`

Comment: Ok @beetroot! > dput(doppelratings2_mit_ID_für_Stackoverflow)
structure(list(ID = c(6584209, 6598108, 6584103, 6552101, 6608303, 
6656213, 9734115, 9554201, 9554108, 9604202, 6660108, 6520103, 
6726215, 6574106, 9762121, 9688202, 9576108), R1 = c(2, 3, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4), R3 = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -17L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: @Jimbou is correct - you should be using `scale_x_continuous`. Try also specifying limits with  `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1:5),ylim=c(1:6))` rather than in `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: @Chris : Jimbou is always right ;)

Comment: However, I'm sure that my data is discrete: Raters attributed levels of language proficiency (A1.1 etc.). These are like marks, and marks are categorical = discrete. It's right that marks are sometimes treated as continuous, but my data works best with the discrete scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
ggplot(data = d, 
       aes(x = R1, y = R3)) +
  geom_jitter(shape = 1, width = 0.1, height = 0.1) + 
  geom_smooth()+
  xlab("Rater 1") +
  ylab("Rater 3") +
  ggtitle("Korrelation zwischen Rater 1 und 3", paste("n = 17 Texte ")) +
  theme_bw(12)+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = min(d$R1):max(d$R1), labels = LETTERS[1:length(min(d$R1):max(d$R1))]) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = min(d$R3):max(d$R3), labels = LETTERS[1:length(min(d$R3):max(d$R3))])
```

[image]

Then you can add `+ coord_cartesian(ylim=c(min(d$R3),6))` to change the limits and to recieve this plot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jimbou! I kept scale_x_discrete as I am sure that my data is discrete, but added 

    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(2,6), xlim=c(2,5))

and it worked: see [chart][1].


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/loXpc.png